# Refer to a subtable without its parent table number

Tags: tables, subfloats

In the MWE below, I want to refer to the subtable `1a` by just display
`a`. I don't want to display the number of the parent `Table 1`.

In this post

[How to reference subfigure in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31823/how-to-reference-subfigure-in-caption),

the first example shows that a solution using `\subbottom`.
However, is there a direct setting for `table` and `subtable` to
achieve what I want?

MWE is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{3cm}
$X \xrightarrow{\phantom{=======}} Y$
\caption{sub-tab}
\label{subtab}
\end{subtable}
\caption{tab}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

This is refer to subtable \ref{subtab}.

\end{document}
```

Thank the answer from `Christian Hupfer`. I am sorry not to be more careful
about my question. In fact, I want to achieve the goal in `beamer`.
I give a MWE below. Using `\subref` in `beamer` will jump to the title page.
Need a way to fix this. But however, `Christian Hupfer`'s answer for `article`
is still helpful!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}


\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{3cm}
$X \xrightarrow{\phantom{=======}} Y$
\caption{sub-tab}
\label{subtab}
\end{subtable}
\caption{tab}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

This is refer to subtable \subref{subtab}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `beamer` and `caption` is a strange relationship. I am not sure that `\subref` can work properly here

Comment: Try `\hyperlink{subtab}{\subref*{subtab}}`. This will at least provide the correct link!

Comment: See the update at the end of my answer please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `subcaption` package defines the command `\subref` which is exactly designed for this usage:

`\ref{foo}` will show the full table number (or caption number) whereas `\subref{foo}` will only show the subtable (or subcaption number)

`subcaption` will define labels of type `sub@foo` and are stripped off driving caption numbers, e. g. a table number here.

`memoir`'s `\subcaptionref` seems to be a similar command but I've never used it so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}



\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{3cm}
$X \xrightarrow{\phantom{=======}} Y$
\caption{sub-tab}
\label{subtab}
\end{subtable}
\caption{tab}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

This is refer to \subref{subtab}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Here's the `beamer` version -- apparently the hyperlink isn't set correctly, so try to extract a `\subref*` and use an automatic hyperlink afterwards by redefinition of `\subref`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}[triangle]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \useoutertheme{infolines}
    \usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
}

\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center]{part title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection\par
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{centering}
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\makeatletter
\let\orig@subref\subref

\renewcommand{\subref}{%
  \@ifstar{\subref@starred}{\subref@unstarred}%
}

\newcommand{\subref@starred}[1]{%
  \orig@subref*{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\subref@unstarred}[1]{%
  \hyperlink{#1}{\orig@subref*{#1}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\begin{frame}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{subtable}{3cm}
$X \xrightarrow{\phantom{=======}} Y$
\caption{sub-tab}
\label{subtab}
\end{subtable}
\caption{tab}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

This is refer to subtable \subref{subtab} %\hyperlink{subtab}{\subref*{subtab}}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @user565739: It's in the manual ;-)

Comment: I found something strange. I use this in `beamer`. Using `\ref` is fine, but using `\subref` will go to the title page. I will give a MWE.

Comment: @user565739: `beamer` was not in your question! You posted an `article` MWE, not a `beamer` version, that's different

Comment: Sorry about this. I didn't realize that this will cause the difference. I just want to give a really minimal "MWE".

Comment: @user565739: You can of course add your MWE, but this changes the question. I'll try to get a solution for it too

Comment: Great again. But I can't give you 2 votes and 2 acceptance.

Comment: @user565739: No, of course not -- but you could look around for other posts of mine ;-) (If you want to upvote in any case only, of course ;-))