# Customize referencing of subcaptions in "memoir"?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, memoir, subcaption

When I use `\subcaption{... \label{myfig}}` in `memoir`, and then reference it, the result is something like "Figure 1(a)". But I would like to customize the reference by removing the parentheses, thus making it appear as "Figure 1a".

How do I do that in `memoir`? I can't find anything in the manual.

Comment: See daleif's comment to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30572/how-to-ref-to-subcaption-numbers-a-b-when-using-memoirs-subcaptions)

Comment: I see. That's annoying, but oh well, I'll have to live with it. Thanks. I suppose this question can be closed due to duplication (funny I didn't find that question when I did a search).

Comment: Perhaps we should merge here: the two sets of answers have useful information in, but really the question is the same.

Comment: @JosephWright I think you're right, they should be merged. Why isn't there a "vote to merge" as well as "vote to close as exact duplicate"

Comment: @Seamus I think first the question has to be closed, and only then can it be merged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do this using some string manipulation from the [`xstring` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring). Using a combination of `\StrBefore` and `\StrBetween`, the "parent" and subfigure numbers can be extracted and printed as in your requirement. However, this would require some more work if needed with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Below is a new macro `\subfigref{<label>}` that should be used to obtain this output, where `<label>` is the reference label used in the subfigure caption. It should also work for other subfloats.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfigures using \subbottom/\subtop
\newcommand*{\subfigref}[1]{\StrBefore{\ref{#1}}{(}\StrBetween{\ref{#1}}{(}{)}\xspace}%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:a}]{\includegraphics{figure1}} \qquad
  \subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:b}]{\includegraphics{figure2}}
  \caption{This is a caption} \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:label}. It has subfigures~\subfigref{fig:label:a} and~\subfigref{fig:label:b}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Werner's, here's a definition that works with **hyperref**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}% Allow subfigures using \subbottom/\subtop

\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand\sref[1]{\edef\next{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\hyperref[#1]{\expandafter\stripparens\next()\nnil}}\x}

\def\stripparens#1(#2)#3\nnil{\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax??\else#1#2\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:a}]{\includegraphics{figure1}} \qquad
  \subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:b}]{\includegraphics{figure2}}
  \caption{This is a caption} \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{fig:label}. It has subfigures~\sref{fig:label:a} and~\sref{fig:label:b}.

\end{document}
```

If **hyperref** is not loaded, then change the definition of `\sref` into

```
\newcommand\sref[1]{\edef\next{\getrefnumber{#1}}%
  \expandafter\stripparens\next()\nnil}
```

It's a kludge and requires `\sref` instead of `\ref`, but it seems to work. When **memoir** will be adapted so that the aspect of references to subfloats is customizable, it will be necessary only to say

```
\let\sref\ref
```