# Using memoir and hyperref, can I get a "\subref" in the caption of a figure?

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, subcaption

I am writing a document using the `memoir` class. I would like to create a figure with two subfigures and to display a caption like "Plot of Y vs X with z=1 (a) and with z=2 (b)", where "(a)" and "(b)" are references to the subfigures.

I read [How to reference subfigure in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31823/how-to-reference-subfigure-in-caption/31875#31875) and [Customize referencing of subcaptions in “memoir”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/customize-referencing-of-subcaptions-in-memoir?lq=1). The following example based on Werner's code  solve my problem.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand*{\subfigref}[1]{(\StrBetween{\ref{#1}}{(}{)})\xspace}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:a}]{\includegraphics{figure1}} \qquad
\subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:b}]{\includegraphics{figure2}}
\caption{These are some awesome figures: \protect\subfigref{fig:label:a} and \protect\subfigref{fig:label:b} }
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I make the previous example work with `hyperref` ? In [Customize referencing of subcaptions in “memoir”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/customize-referencing-of-subcaptions-in-memoir?lq=1), egreg seems to know how to do this but I do not understand enough his answer to use it for this particular problem.

**EDIT**

Note that I would also like to keep references such as "in Figure 0.1(a)" outside the figure.

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `\p@subfigure` which controls the prefix that will be added to the `subfigure` counter:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:a}]{\includegraphics{figure1}} \qquad
\subbottom[This is a subfigure\label{fig:label:b}]{\includegraphics{figure2}}
\caption{These are some awesome figures:~\protect\ref{fig:label:a} and~\protect\ref{fig:label:b} }
\label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, if I use `\ref{fig:label:a}` outside the figure, it will appear as "(a)" and I would like it like "0.1(a)". Using `\begingroup` changes nothing. I edited my question to make this point clearer.

Comment: @Ragnaroob ah, I see. Then my answer is no longer valid; perhaps I will keep it for reference.

Comment: @RaphaëlCoudret perhaps `\subcaptionref` could be helpful. C.f., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115093/37198