# Change style of references to memoir's subfloats

Tags: cross-referencing, memoir, subfloats

Is there a way to configure the style of references to memoir's built-in subfloats, i.e. when using `\subcaptionref`, and `\ref`? For example, is it possible to remove the parentheses?

From the memoir documentation:

```
Figure \ref{fig:twosubfig} has two subfigures,
  namely \ref{sf:1}, \subcaptionref{sf:2}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[Subfigure 1]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE ONE}\label{sf:1}}
\hfill
\subbottom[Subfigure 2]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE TWO}\label{sf:2}}
\caption{Figure with two subfigures} \label{fig:twosubfig}
\end{figure}
```

produces

> Figure 10.19 has two subfigures, namely 10.19(a), (b).

Can this be changed to e.g.

> Figure 10.19 has two subfigures, namely 10.19a, b.

To be clear, the changes should preferably only apply to the reference, not the subcaption itself.

Comment: I have found an answer in the related questions [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30572/how-to-ref-to-subcaption-numbers-a-b-when-using-memoirs-subcaptions?rq=1#comment61296_30573), which says that the parentheses are hardwired as of 2011. Is this still the case?

Comment: It is, it is on my todo list, but not with high priority. You might want to consider the subfig package or similar

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the quick response, if you put this into an answer I'll accept it straight away. As for using another package, it's not important enough for that.

Comment: It is not a real answer for the question,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding parentheses around subfig references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references)

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that I was specifically asking about memoir's options for configuring such a thing, not other packages, which I know of and use regularly. This could be useful for anyone asking themselves "is this possible in memoir or do I need another package?" and therefore, the answer by @daleif is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Werner's answer and a bit of digging through `memoir.cls`, it follows that it is much easier to change the `subfigure` counter to the desired style, e.g. no parentheses, and afterwards fix the subcaption label using the `\@thesubfigure` macro.

[image: changed subfigure reference style]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

% works with and without hyperref
%\usepackage{hyperref}

% create a figure subfloat
\newsubfloat{figure}

% change style
\makeatletter
\def\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\def\@thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})%
            \if@tightsubcap\hskip\subfloatlabelskip\else\space\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Figure \ref{fig:twosubfig} has two subfigures,
  namely \ref{sf:1}, \subcaptionref{sf:2}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subbottom[Subfigure 1]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE ONE}\label{sf:1}}
\hfill
\subbottom[Subfigure 2]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE TWO}\label{sf:2}}
\caption{Figure with two subfigures} \label{fig:twosubfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following updates the way subcaption references are written to the `.aux`, making `\subcaptionref` pull the appropriate non-parenthesized reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\newcommand{\thesubfigureref}{\alph{subfigure}}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \patchcmd{\sf@@memsub@label}% <cmd>
    {\@nameuse{@@thesub\@captype}}% <search>
    {\@nameuse{thesub\@captype ref}}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{9}% Just for this example
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{figure}{18}% Just for this example

Figure \ref{fig:twosubfig} has two subfigures,
  namely \ref{fig:twosubfig}\subcaptionref{sf:1}, \subcaptionref{sf:2}.

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \subbottom[Subfigure 1]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE ONE}\label{sf:1}}
  \subbottom[Subfigure 2]{\fbox{SUBFIGURE TWO}\label{sf:2}}
  \caption{Figure with two subfigures} \label{fig:twosubfig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Changes are required if you're loading the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) (or [`nameref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)) as well.

Comment: If I parse this correctly, the `@@thesub<type>` command is responsible for printing the reference, and is by default defined as `thesub<type>`, which contains the parentheses. Would it therefore not suffice to simply redefine `\@namedef{@@thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}` globally and get the references as I want them for plain, nameref and hyperref all at once?

Comment: Or actually just `\def\@@thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}` as I don't think `\@namedef` does anything else in this case.

Comment: @user5254: Yes, that's a good option. Add `\makeatletter
\def\@@thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}
\makeatother` *after* `\begin{document}`.